# How to remove the OutOfMemoryException when i tried to read a result from web service?

Tags: c#

I am consuming a web service, the web service returns around 100 thousand records, but when I try to read it with the following code it reads it once but the following times the OutOfMemoryException error comes out, someone knows if I am reading the information wrong or how I can remove the exception?

```
        WebResponse response2 = request2.GetResponse();

        string Status2 = 
        ((HttpWebResponse)response2).StatusDescription;


        StringBuilder datos = new StringBuilder();


        StringBuilder _stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
        try
        {

            using ( dataStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader2 = new 
                StreamReader(dataStream2))
                {
                    while (!reader2.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        char[] _buffer = new char[4096];
                        reader2.ReadBlock(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
                        var _bufferString = new String(_buffer);
                        _stringBuilder.Append(_bufferString);
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
        }

    var result2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject> 
      (_stringBuilder.ToString());

       dataStream2.Close();
        response2.Close();
```

I change my code

```
   using ( dataStream2 = response2.GetResponseStream())
            {
                using (StreamReader reader2 = new 
   StreamReader(dataStream2))
                {
                    while (!reader2.EndOfStream)
                    {
                        char[] _buffer = new char[30720];
                        reader2.ReadBlock(_buffer, 0, _buffer.Length);
                        var _bufferString = new String(_buffer);
                        _stringBuilder.Append(_bufferString);
                    }
                    reader2.Close();
                }

            }
```

but the error repeats itself

Comment: This is a very suspect way of reading a string response

Comment: You may need to add a bit more of your code. What do you do with the resulting `_stringBuilder` object? If you keep a bunch of those around in your code, then at some point your application will exhaust the memory available to it. If, however, you discard large objects before reading the next one, then memory will be made available (via garbage collection) for the next run of the block.

Comment: If it has UTF encoding, you could be splitting a character into separate blocks and it won't work well. I would use StringReader class

Comment: `100 thousand records,` How many bytes?

Comment: @ArashMotamedi with the result I want to convert it into a list of objects which each object will be a field (of the response of the webservice), attached to the code

Comment: You should consider using [`HttpClient`, which has a `GetStringAsync`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.http.httpclient.getstringasync?view=netframework-4.8) method. You'll still get an OutOfMemoryException if you don't have enough memory or free up resources correctly, but at least it's one call and no worries about streams and whatnot.

Comment: `already sends the exception of Memory` OK, so the OOM is on the **server**, not the client? If so, please make that **much** clearer in your question.

Comment: Response size is ((HttpWebResponse)response2).ContentLength

Comment: @mjwills The data is around 30K

Comment: Please be clear - is the OOM happening on the **client** or the **server**? A 30K string is **tiny**. I'd be very surprised if it is causing a OOM.

Comment: @mjwills The error is in the client

Comment: Did https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.gcsettings.largeobjectheapcompactionmode?view=netframework-4.8 help? Did you `Dispose` of `response2`?

Comment: `char[] _buffer = new char[30720];` is allocating unnecessarily large numbers of arrays. Consider allocating it outside of the `while` loop, and paying attention to the return value of `ReadBlock`.

Comment: @AlexZ Your new code reads the response in 30K chunks, yet you said the size of "the data" is around 30K: is that per record, or total?

Comment: In fact, "The data" is around to 100 k, not found the  solution yet

Answer (score 0):

*Theoretically* the _buffer object is being re-used between 4K chunks, but it's possible that new allocations are happening.  Further, you're reading *bytes* and then creating UTF-16 *strings* which doubles the amount of memory compared to data that's typically sent as UTF-8 (if it's a web service).  Finally, you're *appending* the string to a StringBuilder, which copies from and then discards its buffer heap memory whenever it needs to expand the buffer.  The garbage collector will have trouble keeping up with the string and StringBuilder allocations, as they're both fragmenting the heap.

If the amount of data sent back by the web service is a significant portion of available heap memory, this could easily cause OOM errors because of the multiplying effect of character encoding and multiple allocations.

Fix this by using a StringReader to read one *line* at a time, and if you know the size of the response in bytes (from the HTTP header), give that as a parameter to the StringBuilder constructor; it will start with its buffer initially allocated to that size so that it allocates only once.  Also consider caching the lines to disk instead of a StringBuilder.

Comment: Change the code to what I understood but it keeps repeating the error, the first time it reads it well but if I do it again the same error comes out

Comment: I answered the question assuming the error was happening on the client, but it's not clear at this point if you're seeing the OOM message coming back from the server.

Comment: @AlexZ Can you try using the JsonConvert Stream API directly?  See https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/DeserializeWithJsonSerializerFromFile.htm